# How to insert programmatically apostrophes into Cell object (Visio Addin)

Tags: c#, office-addins, visio

When i tried to insert aposttrophes into Cell like this:

```
newName = "name with aposttrophes \"";
myShape.Cells[myCell].FormulaU = '"' + newName  + '"';
```

I got the following exception: `"\n\nMissing quote."`

Whether there is way to insert apostrophes to Cell.Formula Visio object?

Comment: Unfortunately, Both are not working.

Comment: @Barns this is actually Visio-specific issue, related to what ".FormulaU" actually is, it's not a plain string propery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; use double-quote:

```
newName = "name with aposttrophes \"\"";
```

Explanation: when you use `.FormulaU` you actually setting a **formula** value. Means, the expression you specify is interpreted by Visio as formula and evaluated. A constant string is a valid expression. Single quote in the string "ends" your formula and you get odd number of quotes in it (unclosed quotes) thus this error message. So before assigning, just duplicate all quotes in the string, like this:

```
myShape.Cells[myCell].FormulaU = '"' + newName.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
```

On reading back (if you use the same `.FormulaU` to read it back, and not `.Characters.Text`, which is preferable, because it calculates fields), do the reverse and de-deuplicate all quotes.

Comment: Got it, but this solution of duplicate all apostrophes is not good for me because logic/business reasons.
So, there is no any option to insert one " to the middle of Formula?
By the way, what is .Characters.Text? I can't find/use this property.

Comment: Please note that will not be duplicated in shape properties, only in the formula. I.e. in the UI they will be fine. Characters.Text: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.characters.text

Comment: In my case,I already use the formula for the UI (by Data Graphics).

Comment: You right! the duplicate is only in the formula inside the ShapeSheet and even for ShapeData it's display like one!